# How to use navigator outside a react component in react-router v6，like axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

How can I navigate in react-router v6? There is no `history` property in `BrowerRouter`. And I don't want to use `window.location.href` to force redirecting.

```
export function setResponseInterceptor(store: AppStore) {
  console.log('setup response interceptor');
  httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
      if (error.isAxiosError && error.response) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 401:
            // dispatch logout action and navigate to `login` page
            break;
          case 404:
            // navigate to 404 page
            break;
          case 500:
            return Promise.reject(new Error(error.response.statusText));
          default:
            return Promise.reject(new Error(error.response.data.message));
        }
      }
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are several ways how to handle this matter.
you have get access to your store(I assume that it is Redux, but does not matter much) inside this action, so it means you may put in the store something like "auth.status: 401 | 404"(a separate 'auth' reducer with value 'status').

So you will not have to deal with router directly in action. Hence you may create 'useEffect' inside your root app component(or implement 'SwitchRouter') where to check what status is being passed down.

then you may use router through react components api like this

```
const history = useHistory(); // hook provided by react-router.
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth.status === 404) history.push('/404');
  if (auth.status === 401) history.push('/login');
}, [auth.status]);
```

otherwise if you use react-sagas - you may use "put" effect inside your saga generator.